# Need Some Help on Python Code

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is My Python Code For Calculating Electricity Bill

```
cust=input("Enter Customer Number\n");
units=input("Enter No of Units\n");

if(units<200&units>0):
        bill=0.50*units;

elif(units>200&units<400):
        bill=100+(0.65*(units-200))
        print"\n in Loop2\n"

elif(units>400&units<600):
       bill=230+(0.80*(units-400))
       print"\n in Loop3\n"

print"Bill For Customer Number ",cust," is ",bill
```

if I give units as 200+ it is in Loop 2 
But if I Give units as 430 it is still running in Loop2

I am New To python so need some help

Comment: You can use this syntax : `if 0<units<200:` ...

Comment: thank you PRMoureu

Comment: Please try to find a question title that's descriptive and specific to the question, so if someone else had already asked it before you could recognize it (and not need to ask again) just from the title. If every question is just "need some help", there's no way to tell if anyone else has asked the same one.

Answer (score 2):

```
cust=input("Enter Customer Number\n");
units=input("Enter No of Units\n");

 if(units<200 and units>0):
    bill=0.50*units

 elif(units>200 and units<400):
    bill=100+(0.65*(units-200))
    print"\n in Loop2\n"

 elif(units>400 and units<600):
   bill=230+(0.80*(units-400))
   print"\n in Loop3\n"

 print"Bill For Customer Number ",cust," is ",bill
```

Use "and" in place of "&".
Boolean operators are usually used on boolean values but bitwise operators are   usually used on integer values. "and" tests whether both expressions are logically True while "&" (when used with True/False values) tests if both are True.